# phpmyadmin cannot login in mysql server

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a problem with MySql.

I have PHP version 5.6, and the last version for phpmyadmin.

I tried using a lot of options but always is the same problem.

I got the error:

> Cannot log in to the MySQL server
>
> mysqli_real_connect(): Server sent charset (255) unknown to the client. Please, report to the developers
>
> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2054): Server sent charset unknown to the client. Please, report to the developers

Also If used `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;`

and username is root, without password is still the same problem.

Comment: I was trying too. I cannot found my.cnf in phpmyadmin folder. I'm talking about localhost/phpmyadmin

Comment: The issue is a (mis)configuration in the MySQL server. Not phpmyadmin.

Comment: I can see i need install xampp and then works